# Static traffic pattern table does not exist

Tags: here-api

I am trying to find the description for the static traffic pattern table on the Here Maps website, but it keeps telling me that "The page you are looking for doesn't exist". I am wondering if the static pattern tables have been removed from Here Maps API?

Here is the link to the page I was referring to:
https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/scontent?region=NA&release=19135&url_root=pde.api.here.com&content=TRAFFIC_PATTERN

Comment: Please refer following documentation to know more about this layer attributes : https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/example-layer.html

Comment: @Arian, can you please provide link to page which navigates to the broken page you shared?

Comment: @Tomas, here is the link: https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/scontent?region=NA&release=19135&url_root=pde.api.here.com&content=TRAFFIC_PATTERN
You need to sign in to the website first to have access to it. You can also first go to this page: https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/scontents?region=NA&release=19135&url_root=pde.api.here.com
and then click on "TRAFFIC_PATTERN"

Comment: There seems to be an ongoing issue with the documentation end point of API for static content. It is being investigated by internal team.

Answer (score 0):

The response to the request contains the following information blocks:

- name of each layer,
  each layer mapping between layers and features tile level for each
  layer

https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/doc/layer.json
?layer=**LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC3**
&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
TRAFFIC_PATTERN_FC1...5 Typical link speed per time of day and weekday
TRAFFIC_SIGN_FC1...5 Traffic sign info for driver alerts
TRAFFIC_SPEED_RECORD_FC1...5 Live traffic info recorded from the last days, in 15 minute resolution
```